# how to turn joined string to list after TextUtils.join

Tags: mysql, android-studio

I'm implementing SQL lite in my application and I'm saving data to it. 
Some of the data I want to save are lists (simple string lists). 
In order to not create an elaborate database, 
I'm using:

```
String joined = TextUtils.join(", ", list);
```

and I'm saving the lists as strings in my database.

The question is now when I want to turn it back into:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

How do I take that string and turn it into a list again ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [TextUtils.split()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#split(java.lang.String,%20java.util.regex.Pattern)).

```
String[] list = TextUtils.split(joined, ", ");
```

> **Returns**
>
> String[]   an array of strings. The array will be empty if text is empty